# MySQL (stored procedure) update rows status column then select updated rows Limit 100

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

Writing QUERY.

First Update 100 rows then pull same 100 records.

I have multiple processes working all are looking same database I don't want duplication because of very fast & heavy transections, some time it get duplicated because of multiple processes pull same records, trying to prevent  duplication issue.

First I want to  update 100 row's column - (status) from 0 to 1 so other process will not see these records then I want to pull same updated records.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`devdba`@`%` PROCEDURE `getQueueRows`()
BEGIN

SET autocommit = 0;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE  Queue
SET status = 1
WHERE status = 0
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 100;

SELECT  * FROM Queue 
where 
status = 1 AND
UPDATED < now();
COMMIT;

END
```

Please advise.

Comment: i have a feeling the UPDATE query does not what it should do.. But you can use `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE` before using the update.. That wil give the records a "read lock" for other clients.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you for quick reply i believe NOWAIT is available in newer versions im using "5.6.36-83.0" giving me error. i have just updated my code please have a look this new code working fine but im not sure this is right way to do or no. please advise.